# BlueImp file selection

Tags: html, .net, blueimp

BlueImp uses a file called .htaccess and in there there is this;

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  ForceType none
</FilesMatch>
```

Does anyone know how to change this so that I can only select .csv files?

No matter what I change, the file dialog;

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple accept=".csv">
```

Always shows "All files", "html files" and "Image Files".

**edit**

On further inspection, the .htaccess file is not required.  IIS was reporting this incorrectly.

The issue is in some of the options;

```
// The regular expression for allowed file types, matches
// against either file type or file name:
   acceptFileTypes: /.+$/i,
// The regular expression to define for which files a preview
// image is shown, matched against the file type:
   previewFileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
```

I can't seem to work out what to change in the above to get a list of .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` files are used by the Apache web server, and may not be related to your HTML input file problem since they control the incoming request to the server.

Try this tag in your HTML:

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple accept="text/csv">
```

"text/csv" is the MIME type for CSV files, and `accept` takes MIME types, not file extensions.

Comment: Didn't work.  Futher, if I remove the .htaccess file I get an error that it's missing.  I should mention I'm using .Net and IIS

Comment: So to confirm, you're just asking how to make the file picker dialog in the web browser restrict the files it will allow the user to upload to CSV files? I'm not clear on how the .htaccess is playing into this.

Comment: And .htaccess files are used by Apache, so why would IIS or your .Net app be using one?

Comment: That is correct and when I remove the htaccess file, which like you say is for apache, i get an error in the js saying "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.options.acceptFileTypes' is null or not an object"